# Use MergeCursor

Tags: android, database-cursor

I have 3 requests to the database, which return Cursor a,b,c. Sample query:

```
public Cursor SearchQueryMoscow (String query ){
         Cursor m;
          a = sqldb.query(true, DataBase.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{KEY_ROWID,ADRESS2,TIME2
                   ,PRICE2,OBJECT2,OPICANIE2,FINDWC2,DISTANSHIONMETRO2,CITY2},CITY2 + " IN ('ROMA') and ("
                    + " adress LIKE " + "'%" + query + "%'" 
                    + " OR gowc LIKE " + "'%" + query + "%'"
                    + " OR timework LIKE " + "'%" + query + "%'"
                    + " OR price LIKE " + "'%" + query + "%'"
                    + " OR mesto LIKE " + "'%" + query + "%'"
                    + " OR opicanie LIKE " + "'%" + query + "%'"
                    + " OR distanshionmetro LIKE " + "'%" + query + "%')"
                   , null, null, null, null, null); 
return a ;}
```

Нow to combine the result of three cursors using MergeCursor?
I wrote:

```
MergeCursor mergecursor = new MergeCursor(mCursors);
```

how to further combine the results of three cursors?
[example seen](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-cts/android/database/cts/MergeCursorTest.java.htm)